# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when launching a java program

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, indexoutofboundsexception, netbeans-8

I am currently working on an assignment but there seems to be a problem when running my code.

```
public class caesar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String inputString = args[0];
        char inputArray[] = inputString.toCharArray();
        int shiftLength = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println("Input: " + inputString);
        String outputString = "";
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at caesar.main(caesar.java:3)

Comment: are you providing any command line input ?

Comment: @amit_183 yes i am ..

Comment: Does your keyboard not have a return key?

Comment: @bpgeck sorry I'm fairly new to this whats that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing command line arguments to your program and don't check whether they are passed. To pass arguments launch your program like

```
java caesar arg0 arg1
```

For example:

```
java caesar somestring 10
```

To do this in NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE, open Project Properties, select the Run item, then specify the arguments there:

[image: program arguments in NetBeans]

You may probably also want to check the number of passed arguments in advance to output the friendly error message. For example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java caesar <inputString> <shift>");
        return;
    }
    ... // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Oo okay. so I've tried this and it just prints out the error message. how can I fix this so it runs the rest of the code?

Comment: @BananaB, have you tried to pass the arguments when you launch the program? How do you launch it in the first place? Command line? Or some IDE button?

Comment: I just run using IDE button

Comment: @BananaB which IDE you are using?

Comment: IDE 8.0.2 does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

[Tagir's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32042754/916225) explained how to pass arguments to the Java class. I want to explain what the exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you try to access an element in an array which does not exists. In your case you are trying to access the first element but the array is empty that's the reason you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Before accessing an array element by index make sure the size of that array is at least index+1. If the index is `n` the size should be `n+1` if not you will get the exception.